# I have a doubt with the phrasal verb "talk someone/yourself out of something", please help me

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I've been trying to make some examples with the phrasal verb ***" talk someone/yourself out of something"***(you can find the definition in Cambridge's Dictionary), and I've come up with this one: **"She talked her boyfriend out of going out with the other girls. The boy agreed begrudgingly"**. I'm very confused about the verb talk because I don't know if I have to add the preposition "to" after it. I asked the unanimous Grammarly and it says that I should do it, but I wanted to hear your opinions. Thank you very much, have a nice day. (Sorry if this message is grammatically incorrect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need *to* with the phrase *talk X out of doing something*. It means 'influence them not to do it by means of talking' I'm sure the dictionary examples don't use *to.*

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.